# How to insert values into a table from 2 tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Using MS Office 2019, I have 2 tables:

- `tblPerson` (`idPerson`, `idCategory`)
- `tblAbsent` (`idPerson`, `idSituation`)

```
tblPerson
-----------------------
idPerson | idCategory |
----------------------+
01       |   03       |
02       |   02       |
03       |   03       |
04       |   01       |
05       |   01       |
06       |   01       |
---------+------------+

tblAbsent
-----------------------+
idPerson | idSituation |
-----------------------+
01       |   02        |
04       |   01        |
05       |   04        |
06       |   01        |
---------+-------------+
```

I want to create 3rd table, containing:

**total**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblPerson
         WHERE idCategory=x
```

**column1**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblAbsent 
         WHERE (idSituation=1 OR idSituation=2) 
         AND idCategory=x
```

**column2**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblAbsent 
         WHERE (idSituation=3 OR idSituation=4) 
         AND idCategory=x
```

**x = {01,02,03}**

```
tblTotal 
-----------+-------+---------+--------+------------------------+
idCategory | total | column1 | column2| total-(column1+column2)|
-----------+-------+---------+--------+------------------------+
01         |  03   |   02    |   01   |           00           |
02         |  01   |   00    |   00   |           01           |
03         |  02   |   01    |   00   |           01           |
-----------+-------+---------+--------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Are the fields text or integer values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables, group by idCategory and use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT p.idCategory,
  COUNT(*) AS total,
  SUM(IIF(a.idSituation IN (1, 2), 1, 0)) AS column1,
  SUM(IIF(a.idSituation IN (3, 4), 1, 0)) AS column2,
  (total - (column1 + column2)) AS column3
FROM tblPerson p LEFT JOIN tblAbsent a
ON a.idPerson = p.idPerson
GROUP BY p.idCategory
```